# Deploy contract error on aurora

Tags: hardhat

```
    contract Test {

    function test2() external pure returns (uint256) {
            return 100;
        }
}
```

An empty contract, use deploy.js:

```
async function main() {
[owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
console.log(`Owner: ${owner.address}`);
const contractName = 'Test';
await hre.run("compile");
console.log("Account balance:", (await owner.getBalance()).toString());
const smartContract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory(contractName);
const contract = await smartContract.deploy();
await contract.deployed();
console.log("Account balance:", (await owner.getBalance()).toString());
console.log(`${contractName} deployed to: ${contract.address}`); 
console.log('Put the above contract address into the .env file under arbContract');
}
```

hardhat.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    aurora: {
      url: 'https://mainnet.aurora.dev',
      accounts: [process.env.privatekey],
      gasPrice: 77777777,
    },
  },
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      { version: "0.8.7" },
      { version: "0.7.6" },
      { version: "0.6.6" }
    ]
  },
};
```

error is

```
  reason: 'transaction failed',
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
```